# How to connect already setup kafka cluster to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

How can I connect kafka events to a mongodb sink?

The resources I found on the net using confluent they make a cluster for you and didn't find how to connect my already existing cluster

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [the Mongo Connector](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/v1.7/sink-connector/) into the `plugin.path` of your connect properties file, then [start Kafka Connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect) using one of the `bin/connect-` scripts in your Kafka installation